# Array to Array group convert

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to convert this array in JavaScript. I have tried many ways but not working...

```js
value = [
  {
      group: "Switzerland",
      id: "A",
      name: "ABC"
  },
  {
      group: "Switzerland",
      id: "B",
      name: "ABC3"
  },
  {
      group: "France",
      id: "C",
      name: "ABC1"
  },
  {
      group: "Italy",
      id: "F",
      name: "ABC3"
  }
]
```

I need to convert the above array to the below array format.

```js
value = [
  {
    name: 'Switzerland',
    bank: [
      {
        group: "Switzerland",
        id: "A",
        name: "ABC"
      },
      {
        group: "Switzerland",
        id: "B",
        name: "ABC3"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'France',
    bank: [
      {
        group: "France",
        id: "C",
        name: "ABC1"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Italy',
    bank: [
      {
        group: "Italy",
        id: "F",
        name: "ABC3"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add your starting point in code. What did you actually try?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the original objects and copy the values into a new object that corresponds to your new model.

```js
let newArray = []

for (let item of value) {
    let newItem = {
        name: item.group,
        bank: [{
            group: item.group,
            id: item.id,
            name: item.name,
        }]
    }
    newArray.push(newItem)
}
```

(You should always include some explanation about what you were trying to achieve and what is the starting point of your code, but hope this helps.)

Answer (score 0):

Go through the items, and build an object with `key` as group.

 when same group item occur, aggregate the values.

```js
const combine = (arr) => {
  const all = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (!all[item.group]) {
      all[item.group] = {
        name: item.group,
        bank: [],
      };
    }
    all[item.group].bank.push({ ...item });
  });
  return Object.values(all);
};

value = [
  {
    group: "Switzerland",
    id: "A",
    name: "ABC",
  },
  {
    group: "Switzerland",
    id: "B",
    name: "ABC3",
  },
  {
    group: "France",
    id: "C",
    name: "ABC1",
  },
  {
    group: "Italy",
    id: "F",
    name: "ABC3",
  },
];

console.log(combine(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your sample

```
function format(data) {
  const arr = [];
  const temp = {};
  data.forEach((obj, index) => {
    const item = { name: obj.group, bank: [] };
    if (temp.hasOwnProperty(obj.group)) {
      arr[temp[obj.group]].bank.push(obj);
    } else {
      item.bank.push(obj);
      arr.push(item);
    }
    temp[obj.group] = index;
  });
  return arr;
}
```

```
console.log(format(value));
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-etadh9